# Aria2c pause and resume every 5 seconds

Tags: aria2

I have a problem with downloading files from a server, the problem is when I start to download files, download speed is good but after a couple, second download speed decreasing.

I am using aria2c and wants to there is any way to pause and resume download every 5 seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem by using aria2c `RPC INTERFACE`.

> aria2 provides JSON-RPC over HTTP and XML-RPC over HTTP interfaces that offer basically the same functionality. aria2 also provides JSON-RPC over WebSocket

I write a script in Node.js which use `aria2.pause` and `aria2.unpause` for pause and resume every 5 seconds