# Aria2c pause and resume every 30 seconds

Tags: node.js, json-rpc, aria2

I have a problem with downloading files from a server, the problem is when I start to download files, download speed is good but after a couple of seconds, downloading speed decreases.

I am using `aria2c` and want to know if there is any way to pause and resume download every 30 seconds?

I have learned from another similar post, he created a script to solve the problem.

I don't know about JS, is there someone can help me build a script? Thanks a lot.

link to the post: [Aria2c pause and resume every 5 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44725279/aria2c-pause-and-resume-every-5-seconds)

Below is what he mentioned:

> I solve my problem by using aria2c RPC INTERFACE.
>
> aria2 provides JSON-RPC over HTTP and XML-RPC over HTTP interfaces that offer >basically the same functionality. aria2 also provides JSON-RPC over WebSocket
>
> I write a script in Node.js which use aria2.pause and aria2.unpause for pause >and resume every 5 seconds

Comment: How much the download speed decreases to? Assuming you are handling all `aria2c` calls from `exec` in NodeJS.

Comment: @Rahil It decreases from 1000+k/s to 20-30k/s. How to call those functions from `exec`? Thanks.

Comment: That's what you need to tell us. How are you currently calling `aria2c` or working with it?

Comment: @RahilWazir I am running `aria2c` in a docker. It has a web-GUI. https://hub.docker.com/r/xujinkai/aria2-with-webui/